# Why am I getting this error while deploying with streamlit?

Tags: deployment, streamlit

I tried installing different versions of streamlit, I went through the code multiple times but I was unable to resolve this error:

```
KeyError: 'postal_path'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\praga\PycharmProjects\Movie-recommender-system\venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\praga\PycharmProjects\Movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 34, in <module>
    names,poster=recommend(selected_movie_name)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\praga\PycharmProjects\Movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 22, in recommend
    recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(movie_id))
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\praga\PycharmProjects\Movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 11, in fetch_poster
    return "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" +data['postal_path']
                                              ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can you please share additional code that is throwing error?